# sed/awk to move content from string to the end of line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

So, I am having the following line in a text file:

```
CN=blabla:client:blablafile.jks, 26-Oct-2019, fabric, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/
```

I need to move the `:blablafile.jks` to the end of the line and the output to be something like:

```
CN=blabla:client, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/, blablafile.jks
```

So, I need to remove the `:` character as well when moving the `blablafile.jks` to the end of the line.

Tried some things with the sed command, but I only sorted out how to move the date to the end of the file. Not sure how should I proceed to have the desired output though.

Can someone help me a bit?

Edit:

Also, can that specific command be built in a way to have all of the `*.jks` files moved to the end of each line?

Basically:

```
CN=blabla:client:blablafile.jks, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/
CN=blabla:client:blablafile31242.jks, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/
CN=blabla:client:blablafile3222242.jks, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/
```

to become:

```
CN=blabla:client, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/, blablafile.jks
CN=blabla:client, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/, blablafile31242.jks
CN=blabla:client, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/, blablafile3222242.jks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(.*):([^,]*\.jks)(,.*)/\1\3, \2/' infile
```

Anything inside `(...)` is known a captured group and they will take a back-reference like `\1` for first group, `\2` for second,... (up to maximum `\9` only).

`:` matches literal `:`
`[^,]*` matches any character except comma;
`\.jks` matches literal dot `.` followed by `jks`

`:[^,]*\.jks,` matches a colon followed by anything that ends with `.jks` and a comma; we want this part `([^,]*\.jks)` to move to last, so we surrounded it within `(...)`; the colon `:` we will remove it, so we left that outside the captured groups.

Outer captured groups captures anything `(.*)` around above captured group; first one is accessible with `\1` "`(.*)`", second with `\2` "`([^,]*\.jks)`" and third `\3` "`(,.*)`".

Answer (score 1):

Tested in GNU `awk`.

- `split()` first field into array `a` and then reassign `$1` to `a[1]` and `a[2]` values and create `$5` with `a[3]` value.
- OFS as separator.

```
awk -F, '{split($1,a,":",sep);$1=a[1]sep[1]a[2];  $5=a[3]; print $0}' OFS=',' file
CN=blabla:client, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/,blablafile.jks
CN=blabla:client, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/,blablafile31242.jks
CN=blabla:client, 26-Oct-2019, server, hostname:/path/to/jks/file/,blablafile3222242.jks
```